# Android Studio fails to debug on my device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am running on Android Studio version

> Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 11 and Android Studio
> Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

on my Mac M1. On both version I am getting this error when i try to debug on my device,

```
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

I tried

1. Invalidate and Restart
2. restarted my machine,
3. restarted the device
4. restarted the ADB Server.

But still having same issue.

Any idea whats happening here?

Comment: What happens if you type 'adb devices' into terminal while the device is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Please check, maybe you have `debuggable false` in your gradle. If so replace to true.

```
debug {
        debuggable true
        ....
    }
```